# Proof that a finite domain is a 'body', a little question

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

In my country a 'body' is defined as $F,+,\cdot$ such that

- $F,+$ is a commutative group
- $F\setminus\{0\}, \cdot$ is a group
- $\cdot$ is distributive to $+$

(while in my country a field is a 'body' where $F,\cdot$ also has the commutative property)

I have a question regarding the proof that a finite domain is a 'body'. (this seems to be know as Wedderburn's little theorem?)

Anyhow the textbook proof goes as follows:

### Proof

Say $R$ is a finite domain, this means that it doesn't contain any zero divisors.

Since a finite domain is a ring, $R\setminus \{0\},\cdot$ has the **(A)** associative property. To prove it is a 'body' we need to prove the **(N)** (neutral) and **(I)** (inversive) properties in $R\setminus \{0\}, \cdot$

We choose $a\in R\setminus \{ 0\}$ en define $f_a: R\setminus \{0\} \to R\setminus\{0\}; x \mapsto ax$.

We prove that $f_a$ is bijective. First of all it's injective since if $f_a(x) = f_a(y)$ then $ax = ay$. And since $F,+$ is a group we can conclude $ax-ay=0$.
The distributive property is valid so $a(x-y)=0$. Because $a\not = 0$ and there aren't any zero divisors this means $x=y$.

> The following is less clear.
>
> - Why does this imply surjectivity?
>
> and especially:
>
> - Why does $R$ contain the 1 (neutral element)? Since we don't know yet that $R,\cdot$ is a group.

Since $f_a$ is an injective mapping of a finite set in itself it must be surjective.

This means that for any given $f(x) = ax \in R\setminus\{0\}$ there is an $x$ in $R\setminus\{ 0\}$. So $ax = 1$ is valid and $x$ is an inverse of $a$.

Since we can setup the proof for any $a$ in $R\setminus\{0\}$ this proves the neutral and inverse properties.

Comment: In English, the term is "field" (Körper is corps in French, though).

Comment: I'm a bit confused now, [link]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics) says a field has "Commutativity of addition and multiplication" and so does a field in my country. But a 'körper' doesn't have this property. Anyway that's just linguistic differences i guess?

Comment: It sounds like what you are describing is a skew field (also called division ring). It was my impression that field in English is called Körper in German, but I might be wrong.

Comment: What is your language? In Portuguese, we say "corpo" (body) for field.

Comment: Ah, skew-field, division-ring, or division-algebra then. But a "Körper" is also commutative, in contrast to a "Schiefkörper", in German.

Comment: In dutch we say "lichaam" (body) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, a domain is assumed to have an identity.  Since $R$ is finite, surjectivity of a map $R \to R$ follows from injectivity: if $x \in R$ were not in the image, then the function would map $n$ elements to at most $n-1$ elements, which means that function is not injective.

Even without assuming the existence of an identity, you can prove it as follows.  We have already proved that both left multiplication by a fixed non-zero element is injective and surjective.  Hence for every nonzero $a \in R$ there exists $x_a \in R$ such that $a x_a = a$.  Multiply on the left by any nonzero $b$ to get $ba x_a = ba$.  But also $ba x_{ba} = ba$ (by definition).  Since $a$ and $b$ are nonzero, so is $ba$, and hence left multiplication by $ba$ is injective, so we conclude that $x_a = x_{ba}$.  But for a fixed nonzero $a$, the elements $ba$ range over all nonzero elements of $R$.  Hence $x_a$'s are all equal, independent of $a$, to some fixed element $x_0$.  We conclude that $a x_0 = a$ for all nonzero $a$, and of course for 0 as well, so this proves that $x_0$ is a right identity for $R$.  By similar arguments (reversing left and right), there is a left identity for $R$, and by a simple argument these two identities must then be equal, so there is an identity.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the surjectivity
But i'm still struggling with that identity... "assumed to have" doesn't seem very proof-like

Comment: What I mean is , some people *define* a domain to have an identity, so there's nothing to prove.  But it turns it out in this case, you can prove it even if you don't define it that way.

Comment: That's nice! Thanks